# QuickFIX/J Failover handling process

Tags: quickfixj

We are using the `QuickFIX/J` library for our application. There is a requirement received to handle the fail-over scenario for the initiator session as below.

If a disconnection experienced for the primary host(`SocketAcceptHost`), we should try the same connection for a configurable number of times.
If all the retry attempts failed only then do we need to start trying to the other hosts(`SocketAcceptHost1, SocketAcceptHost2...SocketAcceptHost[N]`).

As of my understanding, the above requirement is not available with existing code and it seems doable while introducing new parameters to the class "`IoSessionInitiator`". Please be kind enough to advise me further on this.

Comment: Are you using QuickFIX/J (the Java implementation)?

Comment: Yes, We are using QuickFIX/J.

Comment: You've cross-posted this to the QFJ issue tracker at https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/issues/250 which I believe is the correct place for such enhancement requests.